# Expected payoff of Keno's game

Tags: probability

[image]

> A game popular in Nevada gambling casinos is Keno,
> which is played as follows: Twenty numbers are selected at
> random by the casino from the set of numbers 1 through
> 80. A player can select from 1 to 15 numbers; a win occurs
> if some fraction of the player’s chosen subset matches any
> of the 20 numbers drawn by the house. The payoff is a
> function of the number of elements in the player’s selection and the number of matches. For instance, if the player
> selects only 1 number, then he or she wins if this number is
> among the set of 20, and the payoff is $\$2.20$ won for every
> dollar bet. (As the player’s probability of winning in this
> case is 1
> 4 , it is clear that the “fair” payoff should be $\$3$ won
> for every $\$1$ bet.) When the player selects 2 numbers, a
> payoff (of odds) of $\$12$ won for every $\$1$ bet is made when
> both numbers are among the 20.
>
> (a) What would be the fair payoff in this case?
>
> Let Pn, k denote the probability that exactly k of the n
> numbers chosen by the player are among the 20 selected
> by the house.
>
> (b) Compute P(n, k)
>
> (c) The most typical wager at Keno consists of selecting 10
> numbers. For such a bet, the casino pays off as shown in
> the following table. Compute the expected payoff:

- Is Part (b) equal to

$$
\frac{\binom{20}{k}\binom{60}{n - k}}{\binom{80}{n}}
$$

My approach was to consider the $k$ numbers which are the same as that of the house, and multiply by the $n - k$ numbers which are **not** the same as the house.

- I don't quite understand part (c). My understanding was that a single match of the game consists of picking n numbers - so am I supposed to consider multiple independent matches? Or is that k (which would make sense given the payoff table - the larger the k, the harder ot win)? Thanks in advance.

Note that a similar question is at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139439/expected-return-from-casino-keno-game), but that clearly defines what a win is (i.e, $k$ only needs to be positive).

This is from Sheldon Ross' book on A First Introduction to Probability.

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that the result does not depend on the $n$ numbers selected by the player, hence let's assume they are $A=\{1,2, \cdots \cdots n\}$

Then the event that, among the $20$ numbers chosen by the house (from the set $\{1,2 \cdots 80\}$), exactly $k$ of them are in $A$, can ocurr in   $\binom{n}{k}\binom{80-n}{20-k}$ ways. Hence $$P_{n,k}=\frac{\binom{n}{k}\binom{80-n}{20-k}}{\binom{80} {20}}$$

Comment: Your answer helped me in figuring out what the mistake with my initial attempt at $P_{n, k}$ was - I wrote $\binom{80}{n - k}$ instead of $\binom{60}{n - k}$. With that I think our answers are equivalent. 

I'm still stuck on part (c) though.